# Debug Zeppelin Dependency Management

Tags: maven, apache-zeppelin

I try to get the [Zeppelin Dependency Management](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/dependencymanagement.html) working (Zeppelin version 0.6.2).

For example I try  to install the [Spark-Cassandra Connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10) by:

1. Adding a new repository with url: `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/` and no other parameters.
2. Adding a new dependency within the Spark-Interpreter with artifact: `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:2.0.0-M3`

However after saving nothing seems to happen, I can't find any new packages within `~/.m2` and also don't know where to look for logs. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to do a `mvn clean install -U` from the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository is not necessary to add when uses central repository.

Try with following step following.

- `rm -rf local-repo`. This step might not mandatory.
- add artifact dependency in spark interpreter page and click save. At this time the spark interpreter will not start.
- running a simple command like `println("hello world")`
- check the local-repo directory, the dependency jar should be there
- running an import for a class from the added dependency jar

If still not work, checking the log file `zeppelin-interpreter-spark-*.log`.

Comment: Can not really say what I did different, how ever now it works, thanks :)